# How do I get WiX to remove a windows service?

Tags: wix, windows-services

I'm trying to get Wix to remove a windows service upon uninstall.  It adds the service just fine during the install, but during the uninstall, rather than removing the service, it just disables it.  Furthermore, I can't delete it with the command line sc tool because it says that the specified service doesn't exist as an installed service.  If I try to run the installer again, it tells me I don't have sufficient privileges to install system services.  The only way I can get rid of it is to delete it from the registry and reboot the machine.  There has to be a better way to do this.  Here's my component block from the wxs file:

```
<Component Id="MyService.exe" Guid="5187d4cf-c7b7-4f9e-9f2c-2d0557ecdf5e">
    <File Id="MyService.exe" Name="MyService.exe" DiskId="1" Source="$(var.MyService.TargetDir)\MyService.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
    <ServiceInstall Id="MyService.exe" Type="ownProcess" Name="MyService.exe" DisplayName="MyService" Description="MyService"
                    Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Vital="yes" />
    <ServiceControl Id="MyService.exe" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="MyService.exe" Wait="yes" />
  </Component>
```

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the reason the service wasn't deleting was because I had the services MMC open.  Once I closed it and reopened it, the service deleted successfully.

Comment: Good old 'marked for deletion' but won't actually get deleted until you close this window issue.

Comment: @BrianSutherland still relevent in end of 2020